# calculate number column when the value in another column is decreased

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need the formula for the following: one column has a dynamic value: let's say 50. Every time that number is decreased, let's say by 5, I need another column to calculate and display the difference, meaning : 45. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use power automate flow which will run on item creation/update and set the value of number column based on other columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by getting the version history of the list. To do so , one way is through power automate. I have created a "Test" list with number column as "TestCol1" and "FinalDifference" column that will show you the actual difference.

In Power automate follow the below steps.

1. Initialize two variables, in my case it is "columnVersion1Value" and other as "finalValue"
2. "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" with api as below. It will return the first version value of the column "TestCol1"
3. Save the value from the result to your variable 'columnVersion1Value'. Now in variable you have first version of the value. Say first time it was 50.
4. Set the value of the variable "FinalValue" as

   sub(int(variables('columnVersion1Value')),int(triggerOutputs()?['body/TestCol1']))
5. Now you can update the item and set the list item value "FinalDifference" as "FinalValue" variable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Please upvote the answer and marked as answered